# mySQL SUM and COUNT issue, some values on join get doubled

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, sum

I have an issue with this mysql query. basically I need to join one table (**CostiFissi**, a table with costs) with a table with payments (**Pagamenti**), grouping them by cost id (CostiFissi_IdCostoFisso) and calculating the average between monthly sums of payments amount (not just AVG(Totale) ).

*i.e.: the average between 1000+2000 on September and 3000 on October should return 2250 not 3000*

this is what I did so far:

```
SELECT `cf`.`IdCostoFisso`, 
       `cf`.`Nome`, 
       `cf`.`Frequenza`, 
       `cf`.`Importo`, 
       `cf`.`DateFrom`, 
       `cf`.`DateTo`, 
        SUM( p.Totale ) PagamentiTotale, 
        COUNT( p.IdPagamento ) PagamentiNum, 
        AVG(p2.somma_mese) Media 
 FROM (`CostiFissi` cf) 
 LEFT JOIN `Pagamenti` p ON `p`.`CostiFissi_IdCostoFisso` = `cf`.`IdCostoFisso` 
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT MONTH(Data), 
                    YEAR(Data), 
                    CostiFissi_IdCostoFisso, 
                    SUM(Totale) somma_mese 
             FROM Pagamenti 
             GROUP BY YEAR(Data), 
                      MONTH(Data), 
                      CostiFissi_IdCostoFisso 
           ) AS p2 ON `p2`.`CostiFissi_IdCostoFisso` = `cf`.`IdCostoFisso` 
  WHERE `cf`.`DateTo` > '2012-09-27 09:46:14' 
         AND `p`.`Data` >= '2012-01-01 00:00:01' 
         AND `p`.`Data` <= '2012-12-31 23:59:59' 
  GROUP BY `cf`.`IdCostoFisso`
```

than when I run the query I get this issue: say I have 2 costs, cost_a (w/3 payments) and cost_b (w/1 payment), I get back the right mean for both (as I want it to be calculated) but COUNT( p.IdPagamento) returns 6 (and not 3) for cost_a and 1 for cost_b. the same for SUM (p.Totale), that's doubled for cost_a and not for cost_b.

maybe is an issue with table p joining, dunno… it took a while for me to get to this point but now it's a bit messy and I can't get further >_<

ty!

Comment: You're joining first then grouping. Better to group first, then join. It will be much faster, and as an added bonus you'll also get the right result.

Comment: DISTINCT, that was the magic word damn! :D

btw, @MarkByers advice sounds good too ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`COUNT(DISTINCT)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) like so:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT p.IdPagamento)
```

Instead of `COUNT(p.IdPagamento)`.